# How to config automatic sync Jupyter notebook .ipynb and .py files in VSCode e.g. by using Jupytext

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have written some Jupyter notebooks using original Jupyter notebook web interface. All notebooks are synced nicely in this way.

But now, I would like to edit my notebooks in the VSCode. But I cannot configure syncing notebook file with its python script.

I tried this using jupytext:

- created file `jupytext` in the folder `~/.config`
- put the next code into this file:

```
# Always pair ipynb notebooks to py:percent files
default_jupytext_formats = "ipynb,py:percent"
```

But no effect!

**(Update)** Can this be achieved, *as a first solution*, using **VSCode Tasks** (I am not used tasks yet)?

May be it possible to run the task with `jupytext` command **if** the notebook file is **opened/saved/modified**?

Comment: How to understand "syncing notebook file with its python script"? Currently VSCode supports exporting [Jupyter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_export-your-jupyter-notebook) as a python file.

Comment: Jupytext extension in the Jupyter (web version) automatically synchronize the .py file with the .ipynb. So, I working only with .ipynb file and .py file is synced "itself". In VSCode I can manually export the.ipynb into .py. But how I can config the VSCode or Jupytext to synchronize these files in background, by working with notebook file in the VSCode?

Comment: An extension (still in preview) attempts to do just this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.vscode-jupytext

Answer (score 3):

Currently, VSCode does not support such a function. The Jupyter function in VSCode is provided by a Python extension, which supports us to convert between `.ipynb` files and `.py` files in VSCode.

`.ipynb` files to `.py` files : Export as python script.

`.py` files to `.ipynb` files : Right click, "Export Current Python File as Jupyter Notebook"

I have submitted the requirement you described, and we look forward to the realization of this feature. Giuhub link: [How to synchronize the jupyter file and python file of VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14341).

Comment: Can this be achieved, *as a first solution*, using Tasks (I am not used tasks yet)? May be it possible to run the task with ```jupytext``` command **if** the notebook file is **opened/saved/modified**?

Comment: @Andrei Krivoshei -"jupytext" is an extension of "jupyter" and is currently not supported in VSCode.

Comment: ```jupytext``` can be executed for files syncing from a command line. May be it can be automated using *Task in VSCode* for open notebook file on the save operation (I am not familiar with Tasks)?

Comment: @Andrei Krivoshei -For the use of "jupytext" in "Task", we need to do some research, and we will update it here once there is any progress.

Answer (score 1):

I found some issues and really hard to collaborate on Jupytext extensions available, so I have created my own version at: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FrancoMilanese.datascientists-utils

It's similar to those mentioned in other answers and comments, but it includes also export to HTML with a TOC, and also a selection of a user defined python interpreter, if you are using python under a virtual env or something like that, please feel free to try it out.

Collaborations are always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently unsupported by Visual Studio Code.

A feature request with 50 upvotes for it exists at
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1240

The relevant Jupytext feature request is https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext/issues/875 . It sadly has stagnated, so I'm hoping that someone with the right knowledge manages to fix it.